# Why does the while loop keep on going till both variables have reached the target instead of one when I used an OR Boolean Operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

(Sorry the question title is so bad)
When I run the code it works fine till I get to the while loop. It loops till both teams have 5 or more points instead of just till one team hits 5 or more points. I'm not sure why though. I'm pretty new to python and this is one of the few while loops I've done.

```
#Imports random to generate team names and team scores
import random

#Asks for 4 names
team_name1 = input("Please enter a team name. ")
team_name2 = input("Please enter another team name. ")
team_name3 = input("Please enter another team name. ")
team_name4 = input("Please enter another team name. ")

#Puts 2 names in each list
team1_list = [team_name1, team_name2]
team2_list = [team_name3, team_name4]

#Selects a name for each team using the lists
team1 = random.choice(team1_list)
team2 = random.choice(team2_list)

#Sets team score to 0
team1_score = 0
team2_score = 0

#Sets team points to 0
team1_points = 0
team2_points = 0

#The score of each game
def game():
    global team1_score
    global team2_score
    team1_score = random.randint(0,5)
    team2_score = random.randint(0,5)

#If the team won the game, drew or lost
def points():
    global team1_score
    global team2_score
    global team1_points
    global team2_points
    global team1
    global team2
    if team1_score == team2_score:
        team1_points = team1_points + 1
        team2_points = team2_points + 1
        print("It was a draw")
    elif team1_score > team2_score:
        team1_points = team1_points + 3
        team2_points = team2_points + 0
        print(team1, "won the game")
    elif team1_score < team2_score:
        team1_points = team1_points + 0
        team2_points + team2_points + 3
        print(team2, "won the game")

#How many points are needed to win
win = 5

#Stops looping the code when one team has won
while team1_points < win or team2_points < win:
    game()
    points()

#Prints which team won overall
if team1_points > team2_points:
    print(team1, "won with", team1_points, "points.")
    print(team2, "had", team2_points, "points.")
elif team2_points > team1_points:
    print(team2, "won with", team2_points, "points.")
    print(team1, "had", team1_points, "points.")
```

Comment: `team1_points < win` means "team 1 has not yet won", and `team2_points < win` means "team 2 has not yet won". So, your code means "if team 1 has not yet won, _or_ team 2 has not yet won, keep playing" -- so it stays in the loop until both teams have won.

Comment: If you want to exit the loop as soon as _either_ team wins, make it an `and` instead of an `or` combining the have-not-yet-won cases: You want to keep going while _both_ teams have not yet won.

Comment: Thanks it stops when 1 team reaches 5 points now!!!

Comment: Also for some reason the first team entered always gets 5 points and the other team gets 0 points. Why does that happen?

Comment: You have a typo. `team2_points + team2_points + 3` -- the first `+` should be a `=`

Comment: BTW, consider simplifying to `team2_points += 3`.

Comment: (Also, think about encapsulating all your state in an object so you don't need global variables everywhere).

Comment: You might want to acquaint yourself with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).